# send data from two models of Mongoose inside Express.js to display in view list data

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Shopping Website I want to be able to display two model names "jeans" and "shirt" in a view
I need to pass data from two models I know how to access data from two models in one controller but I do not know how to send data from that controller

Controller:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
Shirt = mongoose.model('Shirt'),
Jeans = mongoose.model('Jeans');


exports.list = function(req, res) {

Jeans.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, jeans) {
        Ajean = jeans;
});
Shirt.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, shirts) {
        Ashirt = shirts;
});

Shirt.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(all) {

            // res.jsonp(Ashirt);
            // res.jsonp(Ajean);

});
};
```

View:

```
    <div class="list-group">

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td data-ng-bind="item.name"></td>
                <td data-ng-bind="item.color"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I know that I cannot use "res.jsonp();" more than once .
when I use "Ajean" it give me data for "jeans" and
when I use "Ashirt" it give me data from "shirts" model
But I want to be able to show both data from both "shirt" model and "jean" model

1. How Can I do That?
   Do I need to merge two Json?
2. How should I change my view to see that data?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I completely missunderstood your question. Let me some minutes to explain again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try nesting the queries and then merge the resulting arrays with [**Array.concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
Jeans.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, jeans) {
    Shirt.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, shirts) {
        var all = shirts.concat(jeans);
        res.jsonp(all);
    });
});
```

Comment: you can also use Q module it will return promise